# Extract over 250 fields from a pcap using tshark

Tags: tshark

I have captured wireless traffic using Wireshark and the captured pcap file is approximately 500MB. I'd like to extract more than 250 fields from that capture file. How can I do that with tshark?

Comment: Do you mean over 250 fields (`-e`)?

Comment: yeah. i mean over 250 fields.

Comment: Have you tried to extract more than 250 fields? What was the error message?

Comment: no i dont know how to extract. i only tried export packet dissections as csv. and i am getting only 5 features in that.

Comment: Can't you generate a command line with the 250 fields as arguments (with `-e`)?

Comment: no i dont know the code for the all fields. from where can i get the code for fields? isnt there any command which will extract all possible features from pcap file?

Comment: If you want all the fields for each packet, then you might be looking for the JSON and pdml output format: `tshark -r input.pcap -T pdml` or `tshark -r input.pcap -T json`.

Comment: Awesome!! thanks a lot mate. i got the json output file for one packet. as the json output file for whole packet was over 2GB and couldnt open it. but there arent over 250 fields for one packet. can you tell me how can i capture the traffic so can i have over 250 fields. Thanks a ton!! so far

Comment: That's really dependent on your traffic. You could try capturing packets with multiple encapsulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following tshark commands to extract all fields from your capture file:

```
tshark -r input.pcap -T pdml
tshark -r input.pcap -T json
```

The number of fields you will have in the output really depends on the structure of your packets. You might have a large number of fields if you have several encapsulation layers, or a very small number if you don't have a recognized application layer.